# Password view icon disappears in password editbox

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a password editbox in XPage. When typing chars in the control, the 'Password view icon' shows up the right edge of the control.

However, if the input focus is moved to another control and back to the password control again, the 'Password view icon' never shows up.

Is this a bug? Is there any workaround?
If no workaround, is there a way to hide the "Password view icon" in any case?

Comment: The password editbox is a standard control of XPage. I just checked 'password' option of the editbox control properties.

Comment: This is normal browser related behaviour. Try it on other websites, you will see you can only show passwords as long as you are still focused on the password input.

Comment: I mention about 'Password view icon' which can show password chars when  clicking it. The function always works if the focus is not moved to other control.However if the focus is moved to another, and then back the focus to the password editbox, the function does not work(The password view icon never show up). Perhaps this is a bug. If so, I'd like to disable this icon in any cases. Is it possible?.

Comment: Yes, I know exactly what you mean. But as I said, this is not a bug, this is normal behaviour in password textboxes. To remove the eye completely, add this css to your page: input::-ms-clear, input::-ms-reveal {  display: none;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behaviour in password textboxes. To remove the eye completely, add this css to your page:

```
input::-ms-reveal { 
     display: none;
}
```

Comment: I understand this is a behavior on IE side. I misunderstood this is an issue on XPages side. Thanks!